# POST file with angular 8 progress is wrong in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, angular-httpclient

I tried this [tutorial](https://www.positronx.io/angular-file-upload-with-progress-bar-tutorial/) and it worked fine with the Brave Browser.

When I try e.g. Chrome 78.0.3904.70 64-Bit the progress bar is filling up very fast and then there is a long waiting time to finish the request.

In the browsers DevTools I can see a difference in the timings and I suspect this difference to be the problem of the fast progress bar.

This is the Timings from Brave (with chromium Chrome 78.0.3904.70 64-Bit)
[image: brave is working as expected]

This are the timings from chrome, the "Request send" time is IMHO too short but the TTFB is long...
[image: chrome not]

How to prevent this behavior and always have the exact progress of the uploaded file?

I'm struggling with this problem for some time now and I've tried different tutorials on this topic, but it is always the same problem.

I expect, that the timings of the "Request send" are the time, the file needs to be uploaded and not shifted into the "Waiting (TTFB)"

Comment: Hey - I am having this exact same issue. Did you end up resolving this? Is it an angular 8 issue or something else? I have the same behavior in firefox, too so it doesn't seem specific to a browser.